# javascript match exact string

Tags: javascript, string, matching

how can I check with javascript if one string contains an other string? I have like something like:

```
var a = "Paris, France"
var b = "Paris.."
a.match(b) //returns "Paris, " but should return null
```

I think the problem is that match uses regexp. Is there a possibility to allow Sympols like 
`.,-/\` etc. ?
Thanks

Comment: You don't like `==` ?

Comment: sorry, my bad. i asked it in the wrong way. i wanted to know if a string contains an other string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if one string contains another, use `String.indexOf()`:

```
  var str = 'Paris, France';
  var strIndex = str.indexOf('Paris..');
  if(strIndex == -1) {
     //string not found
  } else {
    //string found
  }
```

But, just in case you want to have a `contains()` function, you can add it to `String` as below:

```
 if(!('contains' in String.prototype)) {
       String.prototype.contains = function(str, startIndex) {
                return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex);
       };
 }

var str = 'Paris, France';
var valid = str.contains('Paris..');
if(valid) {
  //string found
} else {
  //string not found
}
```

Comment: he asks about comparison that checks if one string is equal to another not if it CONTAINS another string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` method:

```
var a = "Paris, France"
var b = "Paris.."
if(a.indexOf(b) != -1){
    //string a contains string b   
}
```